# MIPS Branch Instruction - Getting Branch Location

Tags: c, mips, offset, sign, bitmask

I was wondering how to find the branch location of an instruction such as 
`bne $s1, $s0, label_name`. From what I understand the 16-bit immediate value is a relative offset that should be added to the PC to branch.

What I want to know is how the branch address is calculated as I am finding multiple, contradicting answers for the same thing.

What I have found so far:

1. Increment current PC by four.
2. Shift immediate value (16-bit) left by two (multiply by four).
3. Sign extend immediate value to 32-bits.
4. Add the PC and immediate value.

Is this correct? And if so, how would I sign extend this value in C?

Comment: The branch offset is typically a signed displacement from the address of the next instruction after the branch instruction, so branch 0 would do nothing.

Comment: What I don't understand is how the branch target address is calculated. If I am executing an instruction at 0x400020 and need to jump to 0x400004, how is the new address for the PC calculated? If I add the 16-bit immediate value to the PC, I get an address far larger than what I require.

Comment: It is a signed displacement. But my comments are general, perhaps MIPS isn't like a typical processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation clarify everything.

`PC'=` the next `PC`.

`SignImm=` sign extended immidiate

```
  PC' = PC + 4 + SignImm*4
```

You can get the next `PC` (`PC'`) as following.

1. Add four to the current `PC`.
2. Sign extend the 16 bit immediate.
3. shift left it by 2 and add it to `PC+4`.

**How would I sign extend it in C**

```
     int16_t s = -890;
     int32_t i = s;
```